# Authorizing a Facebook Fan Page for Status Updates

Tags: php, session, facebook

I'm able to update the status on my PROFILE wall using this code:

```
require_once 'facebook-platform/php/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook('APP API KEY','APP SECRET KEY');
$user_id = 'MY USER ID';
$facebook->api_client->users_setStatus('This is a new status');
```

...after authorizing using this address:
http://facebook.com/authorize.php?api_key=MYAPPAPIKEY&v=1.0&ext_perm=publish_stream

This code, however, does not work to update the status on my Facebook PAGE Wall. Are there additional parameters that I can add to the authorize.php url to specify authorizing the PAGE and not just my profile?

Or, are there better ways to post updates to Fan Page Walls?

Thanks!

Comment: You probably have to authorize the app for your page first.  You can check the response from the REST query.  If it responds to you with a 401/403 then the app is not authorized to update the profile.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I solved the problem by consulting the [Facebook desktop application documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/connect_auth/) (even though this is a web application).

I first had to authorize offline access with this url (replacing 'MYAPIKEY'):
http://www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=MYAPIKEY&connect_display=popup&v=1.0&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&cancel_url=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_failure.html&fbconnect=true&return_session=true&session_key_only=true&req_perms=read_stream,publish_stream,offline_access

Then, I needed to grant 'publish_stream' permissions to the PAGE with this url (replacing 'MYAPIKEY' and 'THEPAGEID'):
http://www.facebook.com/connect/prompt_permissions.php?api_key=MYAPIKEY&v=1.0&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html?xxRESULTTOKENxx&display=popup&ext_perm=publish_stream&enable_profile_selector=1&profile_selector_ids=THEPAGEID

I could then use the following code to publish to the Fan Page wall:

```
require_once 'facebook-platform/php/facebook.php';
$facebook = new Facebook(MYAPIKEY, MYAPISECRET);
try{
    $facebook->api_client->stream_publish('INSERT_STATUS_HERE',null,null,null,'THEPAGEID');
}catch(Exception $o ){
    print_r($o);
}
```

Comment: My god, you're awesome. I've been burning my brain out trying to figure out how to grant the page permissions... You're my hero

Comment: I tried working on this but i get FATAL error (Fatal error: Call to a member function stream_publish() on a non-object in ...) . I have given offline authority and publish_stream permissions. I am using the same code.

Comment: Great. Very helpful, thanks!

I've been able to post on my page wall. Unfortunately, I'm the only on able to see my post, which is not really useful. When someone else looks the wall of the page, the post I made using the API doesn't show. Anyone has this issue?

Comment: Nevermind, my app was sandboxed. So Only the publisher was able to see the messages. Works fine, big thanks! :-)

Comment: this is outdated; I've tried just that and it says: "ROR: This endpoint has been deprecated. To temporarily reenable it, you may disable the "august_2012" platform migration. It will be disabled permanently on August 1, 2012."

Answer (score 0):

Based on the above, i tried out a couple of querystring parameters on the graph API authorize URL, and it appears this works:

[https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=[APP_ID]&redirect_uri=[REDIRECT_URL]&scope=publish_stream&enable_profile_selector=1&profile_selector_ids=[PAGE_IDS]](https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=%5BAPP_ID%5D&redirect_uri=%5BREDIRECT_URL%5D&scope=publish_stream&enable_profile_selector=1&profile_selector_ids=%5BPAGE_IDS%5D)

EDIT: Never mind, the above displays all the UI correctly, but still get the "(#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action" error --- it's clear it doesn't work because the access token contains my USER id but not the page's ID.