# Post from facebook app to (fan) page - application has not enough permissions

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have a facebook application, and a facebook (fan) page.
I want to publish to the page, authentified as the app (if possible), from a php script run periodically as a cron job.

I'm using the official facebook php sdk.

I am trying to post to the page with `$facebook->api($pageId."/feed", 'POST', $post);`, where $post contains the required `message` and `link` keys, and should also contain `access_token`.

To get the access token, I tried using `$facebook->getApplicationAccessToken()`, and making a curl request to `https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token` (same result).

The response I get is:
`OAuthException: (#200): The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action`

I was able to post to the page, but with an access_token from `https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts`, which required me to provide a user's access token in the first place. The user's and and his page's tokens seem to expire, at most after 60 days, so this solution is not good.

I tried granting permissions like explained here [Authorizing a Facebook Fan Page for Status Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2110437/250611), but I still get the error from before.

**Any solution on how to post to a facebook page which does not involve user login will be welcome!**

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to post on Page using [Application `access_token`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/applications) and without logging user in (at least once to get an `access_token`, later it can be [extended](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/#extend_token)) and requesting appropriate permissions.

To publish to Page as User you need `publish_stream` permission granted by User.

To publish to Page as Page you need `publish_stream` and `manage_pages` permissions granted by User and [Page `access_token`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/pages/) which can be retrieved from `accounts` connection of [`user`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/).

Comment: So, to clarify, I cannot post to the page without user intervention? I thought that was possible before.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the required access_token for posting to a facebook page via an application using the [Graph API Explorer](http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=145634995501895). In the Explorer:

1. Select the application on behalf of which you want to to do things(post,like, etc.).
2. Enter the url for the page: https://graph.facebook.com/page' in the url field.
3. Click "Get Access Token to get it.
4. You willl get a dialog box; select the permissions to grant to this app.; atleast publish_stream, offline_access & manage_pages( for posting to page wall post)
5. You will get a new access token that you can use with your app. to post to your page.