# Facebook API: Authorizing App to post on a second Fan Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Over PHP we're posting already on a wall of a fan page. Now I created another fan page and I want the same app to post on this wall as well. However, it gives me the same error all the time:

'FacebookRestClientException' with message 'The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action'

The script perfectly posts with the same app on the old page.

I've used already all the links I could find to give permissions to the app for posting on the page's wall. I even got a "Success" but the PHP script answers still with the same error. I know that FB changes the links sometimes.

Apparently they're trying to make it harder and harder, so maybe someone knows links that work giving the right permissions!?

I've already used the links stated here:

[facebook c# sdk - The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6216289/facebook-c-sharp-sdk-the-user-hasnt-authorized-the-application-to-perform-thi)

[Authorizing a Facebook Fan Page for Status Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097665/authorizing-a-facebook-fan-page-for-status-updates)

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following link did the job:

www.facebook.com/login.php?api_key=YOURAPIID&next=http://www.facebook.com/connect/login_success.html&req_perms=read_stream,publish_stream,manage_pages,offline_access

The key was probably the permission to manage_pages because it then asks you again to give the permission for all the pages you currently have.

Good luck everyone!

Comment: Congrats on the fix!  When you are able, please make sure to mark your answer as 'accepted' so that others may learn from your success.  Cheers~