# Facebook. Publish text on facebook wall by clicking image

Tags: php, facebook, api, session, stream

I want to make a facebook app, when user click on image auto publish some text on user's wall.

I have a script:

```
<?php

define('FB_APIKEY', 'YOUR_API');
define('FB_SECRET', 'YOUR_SECRET');
define('FB_SESSION', 'YOUR_SESSION');

require_once('./files/Facebook.php');

echo "post on wall";
try {
  $facebook = new Facebook(FB_APIKEY, FB_SECRET);
  $facebook->api_client->session_key = FB_SESSION;
  $fetch = array(
       'friends' =>array(
           'pattern' => '.*',
           'query' => "select uid2 from friend where uid1={$user}"
            )   
         );
  echo $facebook->api_client->admin_setAppProperties(array('preload_fql' => json_encode($fetch)));

  $message = 'From My App: publish steven on facebook';
  if( $facebook->api_client->stream_publish($message))
    echo "Added on FB Wall";

} catch(Exception $e) {
    echo $e . "<br />";
}
?>
```

As I understand I need to enter my api, secret and session where is called "YOUR_API", "YOUR_SECRET", "YOUR_SESSION".

But how can I get my session key?

When I enter API, SECRET correct, but no session key I got error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function stream_publish() on a non-object in /home/padekime/domains/padekime.wu.lt/public_html/scriptas/index.php on line 12
```

I spent many time, read many tutorials, but not found solution...

Maybe here is any other script to publish some text on user's wall?

When I try this solution:
[Authorizing a Facebook Fan Page for Status Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097665/authorizing-a-facebook-fan-page-for-status-updates)
I got error:

```
FATAL error (Fatal error: Call to a member function stream_publish() on a non-object in ...)
```

When I try this:

```
<?php
$msg = array (
'message' => 'bla bla bla ... bla bla bla...',
'name' => 'The BlaBla Mesage',
'caption' => 'link',
'link' => 'http://www.google.lt',
'description' => 'saf',
'picture' =>'',
'actions' => array(array(
'name' => 'Visit',
'link' => 'http://www.google.lt'))
);
$result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$msg);
var_dump($result);
?>
```

I got error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function api() on a non-object in /home/padekime/domains/padekime.wu.lt/public_html/scriptas/index.php on line 22
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your biggest problem is you are trying to use outdated methods and possibly an out of date PHP SDK. The `api_client()` method does not exist in the current php SDK code.

Start by downloading the [current php SDK from GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk).

There is a complete tutorial of the current method to "Post a Link to a User's Wall" at the [Facebook Developers site](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/). Follow that tutorial with the current SDK and you should be in good shape.