# C# Facebook API - The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action

Tags: c#, facebook, api, oauth

I am having a headache in trying to figure out how to post updates to my Facebook page as I keep receiving the error: **"(OAuthException - #200) (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action"**

I'm writing an offline application that needs to post updates to a Facebook page. I have a Facebook account set up and have a page under this account which is what I'm trying to post to. Through my application, I can post no problem to my own account timeline, but just not to the page timeline itself which has its own page id.

Following reviewing other people's issues with this sort of thing, I have tried a number of things:

- The permissions on the app itself are set to: publish_actions, manage_pages, publish_stream and status_update
- One post suggested that permissions need to be set on the page itself which I have done through what this post suggested: [Authorizing a Facebook Fan Page for Status Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097665/authorizing-a-facebook-fan-page-for-status-updates). Again, the same permissions as above have been used and I manually ran these URLs through my browser and even clicked on "ok" in the dialog when applicable to allow my application access.

My code for this is:

```
var client = new FacebookClient();

dynamic token = client.Get("oauth/access_token", new
{
    client_id = appID,
    client_secret = appSecret,
    grant_type = "client_credentials"
});

client.AccessToken = token.access_token;

dynamic parameters = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();
parameters.title = "Test Title";
parameters.message = "Test Message";

var result = client.Post(pageID + "/feed", parameters);
```

The access token is retrieved and returned so it looks like the page itself isn't accepting the permissions that I'm trying to set on it.

I have tried using the Open Graph Explorer to debug but it seems pretty useless to me!

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: That code looks like you're getting an app access token, not a page token - are you following the login documentation?

Comment: any answer to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Igy, you are using a login flow to request an application access token when you should be using a user access login flow. To post to fan pages you need the page access token.

For offline deprecation guidelines see scenario 5 here https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/